# Getting the "no suitable driver found for..." JDBC error, but I already added the jar to my Eclipse path

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jdbc, runtime-error

Basically I'm trying to connect my eclipse to JDBC, I've already add the external path of jdbcsql to my eclipse.

When I rand my java in code in eclipse, so far I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://HOST:1433;DatabaseName=MASTER
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at insertion.insert_values(insertion.java:12)
```

line 12 revers to this line:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://HOST:1433;DatabaseName=MASTER","sa","password");
```

I uses my SA account for JDBC, and this part of my Java code that connect my eclipse to the JDBC driver:

```
Connection con = null;   PreparedStatement statement = null; //to take care of the sql statements to be run  
//Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");



  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://HOST:1433;DatabaseName=MASTER","sa","ronpaul");
```

Is the problem with my URL or my code syntax, or is it I didn't add the external jar to my eclipse the right way?

I already added the last JDBC driver to my java package path, so what's causing the error? The line 12 has a code syntax error maybe?

Comment: what do you think `No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver` means?

Comment: @ScaryWombat sorry sir I'm just getting started on this, can you write an answer show me how to fix it?

Comment: Just search for jdbc sqlserver driver (google is your friend) and add it to your classpath

Comment: Have a look at [Building the Connection URL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.105).aspx). The URL prefix needs to be `jdbc:sqlserver://...`, not `jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://...`.

Comment: @gord thompson hey sir thank you! I fixed can you write an answer, so I will accept it. just write anything, and I promise I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the problem with my URL

Yes. Microsoft's JDBC Driver for SQL Server uses the URL prefix

```
jdbc:sqlserver://...
```

not

```
jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://...
```

See the MSDN document [Building the Connection URL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.105).aspx) for details.